# What is the equivalent tool for AutoIt in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

I tried to install the [AutoIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) tool with an extension file (.exe file), but I found that a .exe file does not work in Ubuntu. I need to handle my window alert box. I need an AutoIt-like tool. What should I do? Is there an  equivalent tool for AutoIt in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is `actionaz`. You can install it with

```
sudo apt install actionaz
```

Check the [Wiki here](https://wiki.actiona.tools/doku.php?id=en:start)

Another alternative is `xdotool`. Install it with

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Check the [documentation here](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).

And it seems like you can install [Dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/).

You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install python-dogtail
```

And [the documentation](https://vhumpa.fedorapeople.org/dogtail/epydoc/) can help you well.